# Can I use a string value to replace + or - operator in a C# calculation?

Tags: c#

I have a string contained in operationComboBox.Text and I know that the string will be either "+" or "-". I can then perform an addition or subtraction between 2 equations using this code:

```
if ((operationComboBox.Text == "-"))
{
    equation3XCoeff = equations[index1].XCoeff - equations[index2].XCoeff;
    equation3YCoeff = equations[index1].YCoeff - equations[index2].YCoeff;
    equation3Answer = equations[index1].Answer - equations[index2].Answer;
}
else //if (operationComboBox.Text=="+")
{
    equation3XCoeff = equations[index1].XCoeff + equations[index2].XCoeff;
    equation3YCoeff = equations[index1].YCoeff + equations[index2].YCoeff;
    equation3Answer = equations[index1].Answer + equations[index2].Answer;
}
```

My question is, can I get rid of the if statement and use the string value directly in the sums to be performed so as to shorten my code some how? Its probably not too important but I just like my code to be short and the 3 calculations are almost duplicated but for the sign.

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522693/c-sharp-convert-string-to-operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use it directly - it is a string and strings can't be used instead of operator. But based on the text, you can initialize some numeric variable and use it in you equations:

```
var coef = operationComboBox.Text == "-" ? -1 : 1;

equation3XCoeff = equations[index1].XCoeff + coef * equations[index2].XCoeff;
equation3YCoeff = equations[index1].YCoeff + coef * equations[index2].YCoeff;
equation3Answer = equations[index1].Answer + coef * equations[index2].Answer;
```

Comment: Great idea to multiply by (-1) or (+1)! +1

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Nothing, because -(-x) = +x, so -1(-x) = +x. It's ok to use this code.

Comment: it will work as it is supposed to. Let's define `equations[index2].XCoeff` to -2, then `equations[index1].XCoeff - (-2) == equations[index1].XCoeff + (-1) * (-2)`

Comment: I had the multiply by -1 idea too but am not used to using this nice neat case method rather than an if statement. Just what I was after. Thanks. I guess I can use int rather than var too if I wish.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can because the code that you're writting in your visual studio isn't compile into the primitive type 'string'. Visual studio won't be able to interprete it, it will only see that you put some random primitive type 'string' in the middle of nowhere. 
You better try it and you will see that it won't compile.