# How to initialize generic local variable?

Tags: c#, generics

The objective is to create a simple program that calculates the sum of pre-processed set. The `Sum` must be generic to allow it accepts both integer and floating point set.

The following code does not compile. Could you tell me how to fix it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    static class Program
    {
        delegate T del<T>(T x);
        static T Sum<T>(del<T> df, IEnumerable<T> data)
        {
            T s = 0;
            foreach (var x in data) s += df(x);
            return s;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 4);
            int sum = Sum<int>(x => x * x, data);
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Error Messages (roughly speaking):

1. cannot convert `int` to `T`.
2. `+=` is not available for `T`.

Comment: `T s = 0;` should be `T s = default(T);` - Your other error however, cannot be easily solved. Since `T` could be any class (say, `object`), there might not be a `+` operator defined.

Comment: It's ugly, but you could handle the built in number types individually and [use reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251507/is-it-possible-to-call-value-type-operators-via-reflection) to look for a + operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the other issues with your code, you can't do what you're trying to do. C# does not support arithmetic operators on generic types.

Therefore, one option will be to `Sum(del<int>, ..)`, `Sum(del<float>, ...)`.. etc.

Or, use `dynamic`:

```
delegate T del<T>(T x);
static T Sum<T>(del<T> df, IEnumerable<T> data) 
{
    dynamic s = default(T);
    foreach (var x in data) s += df(x);
    return s;
}
```

This results is `30` for your provided example.

Comment: No, there are many valid reasons to do this, C# is just poorly designed for it. In C++ it's trivial.

Comment: I could have sworn your post said "you *don't want to* do what you're trying to do", not "can't".  Sorry if I misread that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the generic `Add()` method defined [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html).

The trick is to pass the initial value of `s` as the type `T` into the `Sum()` method instead of initializing it inside the function.

```
public class Program
{
    public static T Add<T>(T a, T b)
    {
        var paramA = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T), "a");
        var paramB = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T), "b");
        var body = Expression.Add(paramA, paramB);
        var add = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(body, paramA, paramB).Compile();
        return add(a, b);
    }

    public delegate T del<T>(T x);

    //pass the variable s into the function instead of initializing it inside the function.
    public static T Sum<T>(T s, del<T> df, IEnumerable<T> data)
    {
        return data.Aggregate(s, (current, x) => Add(current, df(x)));
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 4);
        int sum = Sum(0, x => x * x, data);
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `default` keyword, specifically:

```
// was: T s = 0;
T s = default(T);
```

I replied in haste to the question in the title, on the secondary issue of performing add operations between generics, this has been covered in [another StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122611/c-sharp-adding-two-generic-values) question, so I wont double post. It involves using `dynamic`, which means you no longer have compile-time safety. Read the other question for more details.

Comment: Again, how does that fix the `+=` issue?

Answer (score 0):

**VERY similar** to Simon Whitehead answer

```
    static T Sum<T>(del<T> df, dynamic data)
    {
        T s = default(T);
        foreach (var x in data) s += df(x);
        return s;
    }
```

this return also 30