# Is there a method in System.Type to get the defined operators for this type?

Tags: c#

I need to know, for a given type, what are the possible operators and what are their possible operand types. Is this possible? 
I have tried the IsSpecialName property, but it doesn't work on types like System.Int32, or System.Boolean. Is there a way to do this for non-user-defined types?

Comment: As mentioned in the comments to the accepted answer to the duplicate question [How to get defined operators for a type in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1412757/215552), there is no way to get the operators for primitive types, since they are mapped directly to IL. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1251514/215552) to the similar question [Is it possible to call value type operators via reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1251507/215552).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. This is an interesting question. There's a previous question, "[How to call custom operator with Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113259/how-to-call-custom-operator-with-reflection)", whose [answer may address your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11113450/3025856).